# Securing a Thrift server aginst the POODLE SSL vulnerability

Tags: java, security, ssl, thrift

In order to secure my Thrift server against the recently discovered [SSLv3 vulnerability](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.cz/2014/10/this-poodle-bites-exploiting-ssl-30.html), I explicitly stated which protocols should be enabled for the server socket:

```scala
TServerSocket socket = TSSLTransportFactory.getServerSocket(...);
SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) socket.getServerSocket;
sslServerSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
```

However, even though a check using the [TestSSLServer](http://www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/) lists only TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2, I'm still able to connect with OpenSSL using SSLv3:

```bash
openssl s_client -connect localhost:1111 -ssl3
```

How can I entirely disable SSLv3 on Thrift, so it fails during the SSL handshake already?

Comment: What gives you sslServerSocket.getEnabledProtocols() and  sslServerSocket.getSupportedProtocols() before and after you set enabled protocols?

Comment: BEFORE_ENABLED:SSLv2Hello,SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 | 
BEFORE_SUPPORTED:SSLv2Hello,SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 | 
AFTER_ENABLED:TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 | 
AFTER_SUPPORTED:SSLv2Hello,SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

Comment: Isn't it possible to set SSLContext instance without SSL? See http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b124/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I misinterpreted the openssl client output. Even though there is `CONNECTED(00000003)` on the first line, the error message follows:

```
140535757866656:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:337:
```

It is, therefore, not possible to connect to the server; the code snippet presented in the question works fine.